# 2 Functions in 1 main program(Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c, visual-studio, function, compiler-construction, int

I wanna add two variables.In my main program are 2 functions. I use Visual Studio 2013.There always appears the error C2660: 'function2': function does not accept arguments 1

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 double funktion1();
 double funktion2();
 int main()
 {
double c;
{
    c=funktion1();
    funktion2(); //LINE 14
}
return 0;
 }
 double funktion1()
 {
double a, b, c;
printf("Add two numbers!");
scanf_s("%lf%lf", &a, &b);
c = a + b;
return c;
 }
 double funktion2(double c)
 {

printf("\n Result: %lf", c); //LINE 29



 }
```

Thx for your help!

Comment: You are printing the value of the variable c that you create locally in funktion2(), and it isn't initialised.

Comment: See *funktion2()* variable c not initialized but going to print in the the next statement.

Comment: `double c;
    printf("\n Result: %lf", c);` you are trying to display a variable that has not been initialized.

Comment: your indentation is bad

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc i just copied it, in visual studio it looks better!

Comment: you should convert from tabs to space before pasting it here. [VS 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/14/how-to-convert-tabs-to-spaces-and-vice-versa-vstipedit0028.aspx) already support this or you can use any source code editor to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use variable `double c` in the statement `printf`. At that point, you haven't assigned a value to `c`. That is what the warning, or error in your case, is telling you.

*Update:*

When you need the return value of `funktion1` in `funktion2`, you must pass it as a parameter, e.g.

```
int main()
{
    double c;
    c = funktion1();
    funktion2(c);
}

/* ... */

void funktion2(double c)
{
    printf("\n Result: %lf", c); //LINE 29
}
```

Comment: should i delete the "double c" line? I need the value of funktion1 in funktion2 to printf!

Comment: You need to change the return type to `void` and modify the forward declaration in line 5 too.